# How to make image blurred but make edges crisp

Tags: html, css, border, blur

Please, don't say anything like OH THERE ARE A LOT OF ANSWERS OUT THERE. I founded a lot of them, but none of them worked. This is HTML:

`<img src="images/ONamaImg.png" class="main-page-img">` (not all of the HMTL of course, only pic code)

And here is CSS:

```
.main-page-img 
{
    filter: grayscale(100%) blur(10px);
    float: right;
    width: 550px;
    height: 700px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 1000px 0px 0px 1000px;
    margin-top: -350px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #777777;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap the image in a container :

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
</div>
```

Then, add these css rules to the container and image:

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: /*add height*/;
    width: /*add width*/;
}

img {
    margin: -10px;
}
```

*Note: I didn't add other styles. Make sure to add them.*

The basic concept is to wrap the blurred image in the container and clip the blurred edges using negative margins.

Answer (score 0):

I also found a lot of answers that don't seen to solve the problem.
Here is my attempt:

### HTML

First I created a container and added an image to use as the crisp border.

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="border-img" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2209676047/gatinho-5755_400x400.jpg" />
  <div class="blur-img"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

Then I use the same image as a background to an epty div inside the container. Within the div backgroud I can scale and adjust the images to make then appear like one.

```
.container {
  width: 450px; 
  height: 500px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.blur-img {
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background-image: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2209676047/gatinho-5755_400x400.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  transform: scale(1.2); /* use scale to zoom image */
  filter: blur(10px);
  position:relative;  /* adjust position */
  left:15%;
  top:15%;
}

.border-img {
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  position:fixed; 
}
```

### Output

And the output looks like this:

[image: blurred face cat]